# ssh problem. Worked fine, installed Mac OS X 10.6.8 update, now doesn't work

Tags: mac, ssh, remote, remote-access

Apologies if this is not the appropriate section for this question...

I'm a newbie as far as dealing with networking issues.  Until last week, I had no problem using ssh to connect to my work Mac from my laptop Mac.  Then I installed an OS update (to OS X 10.6.8).  Now, when I try to ssh, I get "timeout" errors.

I am pretty sure this is not a firewall problem.  In my System Preferences, I have set my firewall to allow incoming ssh connections.

I did:

```
ssh -v me@whereIam.myWork.myCountry
```

and got:

```
    OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
    debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
    debug1: Connecting to whereIam.myWork.myCountry [123.456.789.10] port 22.
    ssh: connect to host whereIam.myWork.myCountry port 22: Operation timed out
```

which makes no sense to me at all!  If anyone could suggest what the problem might be, I would be extremely grateful.  I miss working from my sofa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Did you update both machines or just one? If so which one?

2) If you take your laptop to the office, can you ssh to the machine there?

3) Are you connecting via VPN? If so, can you access other office resources without issue?

Comment: Thanks for your help. 1) Both. 2) I have tried that and I can't. I'm sitting right next to my Desktop computer right now with my laptop; I'm on the same network.  Still doesn't work.  3) I can access other office resources.  I did try connecting via VPN from home (puts me on work network) and that didn't help.

Comment: P.S.  The reason I think the update was the cause--aside from the timing--is that I first updated the laptop, then started having ssh problems.  I couldn't connect, but the connection would come right after an hour or two.  I THEN updated the OS on the work Desktop MacPro and since then ssh has not worked at all.  But I can still ssh into a colleagues Linux.

Comment: `code`ps -aef | grep ssh `code` on the machine you're trying to connect to. If the ssh daemon is not running re-enable it. You're only using password and not ssh keys?

Comment: Thanks...  I'll try that.  But what is an ssh key?

Comment: Well, I may not have understood correctly...  I did: codeps -aef | grep ssh code.  I got: grep: code: No such file or directory, -bash: codeps: command not found

Comment: my bad, I was trying to use markup in the comment. just use ps -aef | grep ssh

Comment: user90276. Thanks a lot. I figured out my problem.  I took a look at my advanced firewall settings and saw an option: sshd-keygen-wrapper that was set at: block incoming connections.  I hadn't noticed it before and wouldn't have even realized this is related to ssh, but the mention of "keys" here was a clue!  Anyway, I reset it and everything works. Thanks for your command suggestion; I'll keep that handy.